# Karate * configure report showAllSteps = false doesn't suppress steps in HTML report

Tags: karate

I am using a `main.feature` file to call other `.feature` files. I want to generate a report to only show the pass/fail condition of each API calls in each feature file called by `main.feature`. The default report provides a lot more information than I need and I want to leave only the `comments`, `Given`, `And`, `When`, and `Then` in my report. However, following the documentation and including `* configure report = false` does not remove steps starting with * in my report. I also tried to do `* configure report = {showLog: false, showAllSteps: false}`, but only `showLog` is working as expected and steps starting with * still appears in the HTML report (I don't have any `* print`). I tried including `karate.configure('report', {showLog: false, showAllSteps: false});` and `karate.configure('report', false);` in my `karate-config.js`, but the issue was still not resolved. I then tried running each individual feature file following the above steps only to end up with the same result. I saw that related issues were marked as fixed. Please let me know if this is still an ongoing bug and if there's something I can do to resolve this issue.

Comment: I've linked to all the available info. maybe there are bugs or maybe there are limitations, you are encouraged to do some research and write a custom report - or contribute code to improve karate.